# Is it necessary to average the shap values ​that have been processed through cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, shap

Is it necessary to average the shap values ​​that have been processed through cross validation?

I saw [a post in Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-shap-with-cross-validation-d24af548fadc) that calculated the shap value through 10 CV and then averaged it. The author stated that the reason for averaging was reliability. My question is, do I really need to average?

For example, let's say you have 1000 pieces of data and divide it 8:2 to use only 200 pieces for the test set. Then, 200 shap values ​​are also created. If you do 10 cv, 100 shap values ​​are used in the test set 10 times, resulting in a total of 1000 shap values.

if you do cross validation, you can get 5 times more shap values than when you do single learning. This means that there are 5 times more cases, so doesn't this in itself provide enough credibility for the results?